# Manipulating /etc/hosts file using Go

Tags: beginner, file, go

This is my first go at a Go program that's not a variation of "Hello {$name}". It's about twice as long as my previous Python implementation, and perhaps an order of magnitude messier.

The goal is to read in /etc/hosts and combine the various entries I've made over time:

```
127.0.0.1 host1.test
127.0.0.1 host2.test
111.111.111.111 staging.dev otherproject.dev
127.0.0.1 localhost host.test
```

into:

```
127.0.0.1 host.test host1.test host2.test localhost
111.111.111.111 otherproject.dev staging.dev
```

Any thoughts on how to make this cleaner, better, and/or more idiomatic?

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "sort"
)

// Because this doesn't exist?
type StringSet struct {
    set map[string]bool
}

func NewStringSet() StringSet {
    return StringSet{ make(map[string]bool) }
}

// Returns true if added, false if already exists
func (s StringSet) Add(str string) bool {
    _, found := s.set[str]
    s.set[str] = true
    return !found
}
// Returns the hostnames in alphabetical order
func (s StringSet) GetHostnames() []string {
    keys := make([]string, 0, len(s.set))
    for key := range s.set {
        keys = append(keys, key)
    }
    sort.Strings(keys)
    return keys
}

// Because this doesn't exist?
func pop(s []string) (string, []string) {
    var x string
    x, s = s[0], s[1:len(s)]
    return x, s
}

// Returns the lines of a file
func GetLines(filename string) []string {
    raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/etc/hosts")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return strings.Split(string(raw[:]), "\n")
}

func WriteHostsFile(outfile string, hosts map[string]StringSet) bool {
    // Range outputs a random order -.-
    fd, err := os.Create(outfile)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer fd.Close()

    fd.WriteString("# Managed by hosts.go\n")

    for k := range hosts {
        names := hosts[k].GetHostnames()
        line := k + " " + strings.Join(names, " ")
        fd.WriteString(line + "\n")
    }

    return true
}

func ProcessHosts(data []string) map[string]StringSet {
    hosts := make(map[string]StringSet)
    for _, line := range data {
        var ip string
        parts := strings.Split(line, " ")

        if len(parts) > 1 {
            ip, parts = pop(parts)
            if ip[0] == '#' {
                continue
            }

            // Check if nil map
            if len(hosts[ip].set) == 0 {
                hosts[ip] = NewStringSet()
            }

            for _, word := range parts {
                hosts[ip].Add(word)
            }
        }
    }
    return hosts
}

func main() {
    data := GetLines("/etc/hosts")
    hosts := ProcessHosts(data)
    WriteHostsFile("hosts", hosts)
}
```

Comment: It feels like a large portion of the code is just to create things which I believe you used in your Python implementation (e.g. `pop` and `StringSet`). To truly learn Go, I would highly advise rethinking the problem in terms of what's available in Go (maps and slices) and then doing it from scratch, rather than creating new generic structures. Most notably, I'd use a map[string][]string to store IP -> slice of hostnames and not care about duplicates, then remove them after you sort the slice.

Comment: Also, I recommend using bufio.Scanner instead of loading the whole file into memory and then splitting by new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First pass on your code:

- [Don't panic.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#dont-panic) For example, your `WriteHostsFile` function should return `error` instead of `bool`.
- Don't create a special struct for a string set. Just use `map[string]bool` and [exploit zero values](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) =) Don't be afraid to use `map[string]map[string]bool` to represent your hosts.

  - Your `Add` function go away, but fyi: you are making it return a bool and never using it.
- Your `pop` function could be simplified and inlined. Just use `ip, parts = parts[0], parts[1:]`.
- Check for nil value using `foo == nil` instead of `len(foo) == 0`.
- `strings.Split(line, " ")` only works if things are separated with spaces — but indentations are a perfectly valid separator for `/etc/hosts` =)
- If your lines aren't too long (and you can probably assume lines from `/etc/hosts` are going to be smaller than 65k chars), use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewScanner) to read a file line by line. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757389/reading-file-line-by-line-in-go) for a full example and a discussion of caveats.

  - Your `GetLines` function should probably be inlined, but fyi: you're silently discarding its argument.
- You probably want to use flags for the input and output paths, and output on `stdout` by default (maybe have a flag to override `/etc/hosts`). Outputting to a file named `hosts` in the current directory is pretty unexpected.
- Instead of `for k := range hosts` and then calling `hosts[k]`, you can use directly `for k, h := range hosts` and use h.
- You don't want to write into a file line by line — what if you're overwriting the original file and your binary fails in the middle? You probably want to have `WriteHostsFile` write into a [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) and write everything at once at the end.
- All your functions are exported (they start with an uppercase letter), but this is not a library; so you shouldn't export anything: they should all start with a lowercase letter.
- Your algorithm is not deterministic, because you're iterating over the elements of a map in `WriteHostsFile`: it might be unexpected to see the file modified if all hosts are already correctly grouped. Sorting the hosts by key; or by first appearance in the original file, would solve this.

Cheers!